# How to use MediaQuery from react-responsive to hide only one JSX attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

A button element that contains a **Profile Picture** and the **Info** which is the first-name and the last-name. What I want is to hide only the `profileImageProps={profileImageAndBasicInfoProps.profileImageProps}` which is the profile picture when the screen size is smaller than 768px. I have wrapped the button element with the `MediaQuery` tags from react-responsive. But it will of course hide the whole element.

> Code below:

```
<MediaQuery minWidth={768}>
                <button className="btn btn-link" onClick={onUserClick}><ProfileImageAndBasicInfo     
                  profileImageProps={profileImageAndBasicInfoProps.profileImageProps}
                  basicInfoProps={profileImageAndBasicInfoProps.basicInfoProps}
                  data={{
                      firstName: props.user.attendee.first_name,
                      lastName: props.user.attendee.last_name
                    }}/>
                </button>
</MediaQuery>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which tool/library you are using, but either way, you'll need to change the approach (example using [MUI](https://material-ui.com/components/use-media-query/#simple-media-query)):

```js
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const matches = useMediaQuery("(min-width:768px)");

  return (
    <button>
      <ProfileImageAndBasicInfo
        profileImageProps={matches ? profileImageAndBasicInfoProps.profileImageProps : undefined}
      />
    </button>
  );
};
```